# Insecure VPN entry point

Tags: vpn, router

If I use an insecure router as an entry point of a VPN, does this effectively bypass all of the privacy benefits of using a VPN?

Answer (score 1):

VPN is designed to protect against attackers on the path of the communication between the VPN endpoints. This means it is does not protect against attackers before or at the VPN entry or at or after the VPN exit. This means an insecure router as VPN entry seriously impacts the protection offered by the VPN - an attacker could simply attack the VPN entry and access the communication before encryption or after decryption.

Comment: @user215422:  Comments should be in the context of the original question and not ask a new question like you did. Also, there is likely already an existing question on this site which covers this, so please search first and if you find nothing ask a new question.